# цикл for с рандомными индексами

Tags: javascript

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Этот код выведет последовательность 0-9.

Вопрос.  Как вывести эту последовательность(всю) в случайном порядке.

Хочется увидеть самую чистую и правильную реализацию

Comment: А какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: `Хочется увидеть самую чистую и правильную реализацию` - а каковы критерии чистоты и правильности?

Comment: Критерий чистоты - небольшой объем кода, правильности - согласие большинства тех, кто в этом разбираеться

Comment: Вообще я не решаю никакую конкретную задачу, просто мне это интересно

Comment: @antonin14d правильно будет заполнить массив и перемешать

Comment: @antonin14d в отрыве от конкретной задачи любые варианты будут правильными)

Answer (score 2):

Короткий, но к сожалению, дающий неравномерное распределение способ:

```js
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; arr[i] = i++);
arr.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
console.log(arr);
```

Альтернативный, более корректный вариант:

```js
function shuffle(n) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; arr[i] = i++);
  return arr.map(a => {
    return {
      val: a,
      rnd: Math.random()
    }
  }).sort((a, b) => a.rnd - b.rnd).map(a => a.val)
}

console.log(shuffle(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Если *чистый*, это без жуквери и андерскора/лоудаша, то вот так работает *правильно*: 
 =)

```js
const range = 10;
let used = {};
for (let i = 0; i < range; ++i) {
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (range - i));
  console.log((r in used) ? used[r] : r);
  let l = range - i - 1;
  used[r] = (l in used) ? used[l] : l;
}
```

С [lodash](https://lodash.com/) будет короче:

```js
_.forEach(_.shuffle(_.range(0,10)), function(v) {
    console.log(v);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

вариант

```js
"use strict"
const range = 10;
let used = Array(range);
for (let i = 0; i < range; ++i) {
  let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * range);
  let l = used[i] !== void(0) ? used[i] : i;
  used[i] = used[r] !== void(0) ? used[r] : r;
  used[r] = l;
}
console.log(used);
```